# What should be the endpoint address when I use Flutter + Deno?

Tags: flutter, android-emulator, crud, endpoint, deno

I am using Flutter, VSCode and Android emulator in Windows 10. Also Deno as the backend server. I am trying to connect Flutter app to Deno app locally in my PC. But I don't know what address exactly I must use?

This is the address I am trying to send `get, post, etc.` requests from the Flutter app to:

```
http://10.0.2.2:8000/api/register
```

And this is the address I am trying to receive those requests inside my deno app:

```
Listening on: http://0.0.0.0:8000
```

And the endpoints such as `/api/register` work when I use postman to test them with the follwong address for example:

```
0.0.0.0:8000/api/register
```

I don't know what is the problem and how can I fix it?

Comment: What about updating your Flutter app to call http://0.0.0.0:8000/api/register instead of http://10.0.2.2:8000/api/register?

Comment: Similar to the comment by @mfulton26: You might want to try `http://localhost:8000/api/register` as the address

Comment: @mfulton26: By doing that I get this error `socketexception os error connection refused errno = 111 address = 0.0.0.0.port=33668`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that when I use Android Emulator and want to point out to the `http://localhost` I must use the following address:

```
http://10.0.2.2
```

This means `localhost` in the Android Emulator.